# Passing Variables Between Plays In Playbook

Tags: ansible

I am trying to automate server reboots after server updates in Ansible.

To reboot a server I need to check if its redundant servers are up first. So if HostA requires a reboot I need to first check if HostB and HostC are up and running the service (EMQX in this case) and then let Host A know if it is okay to reboot or not.

Here is the code I currently have where I am unable to pass parameters between plays, what would be the best way to accomplish this?

```
---
- name: HostA Reboot Required Check
  hosts: HostA
  remote_user: ansible
  tasks:
    - name: Check If Reboot Required Exists
      stat:
        path: /var/run/reboot-required
      register: reboot_required
    - debug:
        msg: "Reboot Required"
      when: reboot_required.stat.exists
    - set_fact:
        hostvars.localhost.host_a_reboot_required = true
      when: reboot_required.stat.exists

- name: HostA Redundancy Check
  hosts: [HostB, HostC]
  remote_user: ansible
  tasks:
    - name: Check If EMQX is Running On HostB & HostC
      ansible.builtin.systemd:
        state: started
        name: emqx
      when: hostvars.localhost.host_a_reboot_required


# Still Need To Add Code to Reboot Host A if HostB and HostC Are Up.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
- set_fact:
  hostvars.localhost.host_a_reboot_required = true
```

First, that's invalid syntax; it doesn't result in an error, but neither does it create a fact. The argument to `set_fact` need to be a dictionary, which would look like:

```
- set_fact:
    hostvars.localhost.host_a_reboot_required: true
  when: reboot_required.stat.exists
```

But you can't create a variable on another host with that syntax; that will simply result in an error:

> `An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: NoneType: None fatal: [HostA]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "The variable name 'hostvars.localhost.host_a_reboot_required' is not valid. Variables must start with a letter or underscore character, and contain only letters, numbers and underscores."}`

---

You're *already* setting a variable named `reboot_required` on `HostA` as the result of your `register:` directive. Just use that in your conditionals:

```
- name: HostA Redundancy Check
  hosts: [HostB, HostC]
  tasks:
    - name: Check If EMQX is Running On HostB & HostC
      ansible.builtin.systemd:
        state: started
        name: emqx
      when: hostvars.HostA.reboot_required.stat.exists
```

That gives us the following complete playbook:

```
- name: HostA Reboot Required Check
  hosts: HostA
  tasks:
    - name: Check If Reboot Required Exists
      stat:
        path: /var/run/reboot-required
      register: reboot_required
    - debug:
        msg: "Reboot Required"
      when: reboot_required.stat.exists

- name: HostA Redundancy Check
  hosts: [HostB, HostC]
  tasks:
    - name: Check If EMQX is Running On HostB & HostC
      ansible.builtin.systemd:
        state: started
        name: emqx
      when: hostvars.HostA.reboot_required.stat.exists
```

---

If you want to have a simple variable name (`reboot_required`) instead of using a structured variable (`reboot_required.stat.exists`), rename the variable you use in the `register` directive and then use `set_fact` to create the desired variable:

```
- name: HostA Reboot Required Check
  hosts: HostA
  tasks:
    - name: Check If Reboot Required Exists
      stat:
        path: /var/run/reboot-required
      register: reboot_required_stat
    - debug:
        msg: "Reboot Required"
      when: reboot_required_stat.stat.exists
    - set_fact:
        reboot_required: "{{ reboot_required_stat.stat.exists }}"

- name: HostA Redundancy Check
  hosts: [HostB, HostC]
  tasks:
    - name: Check If EMQX is Running On HostB & HostC
      debug:
        msg:
          ansible.builtin.systemd:
            state: started
            name: emqx
      when: hostvars.HostA.reboot_required
```

Comment: Thanks you, this worked well for me. One more question, if I was trying to use variable hosts such as  {{ server }} for HostA, how would this change the hostvars.HostA string?

Comment: You would write something like `hostvars[server].reboot_required`